# I know Galois theory is used to study fields using properties of groups. Is it ever used to study groups using properties of fields?

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory

More specifically, are there any results in pure, abstract group theory that are most easily proved using Galois theory?

Comment: The representation theoretic proof that groups of order $p^a q^b$ are solvable uses a bit of Galois theory (at least, the version that I learned did). (It was used in a lemma about averaging roots of unity.)

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the comment of AreaMan, I'd say that [character theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_theory) is a possible, positive answer. Just check the Wikipedia article to see the role played by algebraic integers- they are indeed a key ingredient in the proof of [Burnside's $p^{a} q^{b}$ theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside_theorem).